# How should you delete rows with a unique value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to delete all rows in a table that have a unique value in the `setid` column. I can select them like this:

```
select * from imagesets as a 
where (select count(*) from imagesets as b where a.setid = b.setid) = 1
```

What's the best way to delete them? Is there a better way to select them?

Comment: You can optimize the subquery by adding a `LIMIT 2`, as you aren't interested in any more results. Delete-action is explained below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following will work in MySQL:

```
delete i from imagesets i join
            (select setid, count(*) as cnt
             from imagesets
             group by setid
             having count(*) = 1
            ) set1
            on i.setid = set1.setid;
```

Comment: In that case most likely you need to state what table to delete from explicitly: `delete imagesets from imagesets ...` (-1 isn't mine)

Comment: @zerkms . . . Yes, that was missing from the delete statement.  Not so sure that omission was worth a downvote.  You can see it work here (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aceb8/1).

Comment: I believe it works and +1 to restore the balance :-)

Comment: I prefer the method without creating a temp table. I joined and selected id (unique key) instead of setid, which I neglected to mention existed.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE to_delete AS
    SELECT setid FROM imagesets GROUP BY setid HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;

DELETE imagesets FROM imagesets NATURAL JOIN to_delete;
DROP TABLE to_delete;
```

The last line is optional. Temporary tables are removed automatically by the end of the session.

Aparently this works too:

```
DELETE imagesets FROM imagesets NATURAL JOIN (SELECT setid FROM imagesets GROUP BY setid HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) singles;
```

Despite it's using a `SELECT` inside the `DELETE` statement, the way MySQL handles this query don't seem to create conflicts with table locking. According to the Processes List, MySQL is automatically generating a temporary table when doing this. I cannot tell howover, that it will work for every version of MySQL.

Comment: `DROP TABLE` might be redundant in this case, isn't it?

Comment: it takes some time. So if you do that explicitly - your program have to wait for `DROP` to succeed. PS: that's why I said "*might*" - if it's not required - I cannot think of a good reason to do so.

Comment: He might for instance be using PDO with persistant connections. It won't remove temporary tables between sessions, because, there will be no "between sessions". In addition he will be only able to run this script once per session if he don't drop the table.

Comment: yep, that's what the "*might*" word for :-)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp.deletesetids AS 
select setid from imagesets as a 
where (select count(*) from imagesets as b where a.setid = b.setid) = 1;

DELETE t1 FROM imagesets t1 JOIN temp.deletesetids t2 
WHERE t1.SEtId=t2.SEtId;

DROP TABLE temp.deletesetids;
```

This does require you have a temp `SCHEMA`. Otherwise just use your current session selection

Comment: If you used temporary table - you wouldn't have to drop it manually (and didn't need a `temp` database)

Comment: zerkms, you still have to drop the table even though it is a temporary table. it is temporary until you remove it or the session does as i just read. Try CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test AS SELECT 1,2; twice. It gave me error table allready exists.